# Elasticsearch, eliminate results over ti

Tags: elasticsearch, sequence, aggregation

I have a data set with time and locations. I query every document, based on "object_id" with value "Jeroen"

The result set is ordered by timevalue. (green)

What I want is the expected result. (blue)
[image: results vs expected result]

As you see, new york is listed twice, because I want to see every "change over time", not a unique count.

How can I do that at once with Elastic? An aggregation? Extra field with a script that says: "doc[i].location == doc[i-1].location ?
Does that perform with about 10.000 entries?

Of course I can process the results afterwards in code, but it would be fun with ES!

Thanks in advance

Comment: HI it is not clear to me what you wish to achieve. Could you explain a bit more what is it that you want to do ?

You would like to get a list of all the cities order by timestamps deduplicated. ?

Could you give us a sample of your data

Comment: After doodling around ... I am not sure I could find a way to do it in elasticsearch

Comment: Imagine an airplane starts in New York, and has 4 stops in New York. I want to see the last stop. (4, New York). Then the plane flies to San Francisco, and again to another airport in SF, I want to see this stop (6, San Francisco). Then New york and denver.

Answer (score 0):

if you are storing all the results in an index and you only want the latest one, then look at running https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.3/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html on the `timevalue` field for each of the `location` values